# Databricks-Connect: Missing sparkContext

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

I have issues using the newest version of databricks-connect (13.3.0). I would like to access the sparkContext and tried it as it worked for databricks-connect<13.0:

```
from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession
spark = DatabricksSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext
```

However, now I get the error:

> pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkNotImplementedError: [NOT_IMPLEMENTED] sparkContext() is not implemented.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Databricks connect in versions 13+ is based on Spark Connect that  doesn't support RDD APIs together with related objects like SparkContext.  It's really [documented](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/databricks-connect-ref.html#pyspark-dataframe-api-limitations) as known limitation.